# Display message to terminal with freewrap for tcltk?

Tags: tcl, tcltk

I am using freewrap to package a program into a single file. It seems freewrap has two options `freewrap` and `freewrapTCLSH`. Since `freewrapTCLSH` was created for a command line tool in mind it displays any `puts "some text"` to the terminal. However, with `freewrap` any `puts "some text"` does not show on the terminal.

The program is GUI based so I cannot use `freewrapTCLSH`. However, it uses procedures that displays info to the terminal. While there might be a better way to show info for a GUI based program, these procedures are third party so I cannot change the fact that info is trying to be sent to the terminal.

Is there a way for a `freewrap` program to display info to the terminal?

Comment: Try putting `console show` at the start of your program.

Comment: That does work, it will give me a separate window that shows the terminal outputs. Even though it is a GUI program, I start it by calling the executable from the terminal. Do you know if there is a way for the output to go directly to that terminal?

Comment: Perhaps you could try using a different packaging method for your program.  I find http://www.ch-werner.de/cgi-bin/luck.pl pretty good.